# I am migrating spring boot version 2.7.3 to spring-boot 3.0.0 so existing code is breaking related EntityManagerfactory is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, java-17

In below I am creating EntityManagerfactory object and EntityManager object

```
    @Override
    public boolean isTenantSchemaExist(String tenantId) {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = 
            Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
        Query getSchemasQuery = manager.createNativeQuery(TENANT_SCHEMA_EXIST_QUERY);
        List<String> tenantSchemas = new ArrayList(getSchemasQuery.getResultList());
        return tenantSchemas.contains(tenantId);
    }
```

Below is build.gradle file content

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.1"
    implementation "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.1"
    implementation "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api:2.17.1"
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.17.1'
    implementation "com.nexidia:nexidia-semanticanalysis:${semanticanalysisVersion}"
    implementation(group: 'com.nexidia', name: 'nexidia-workbench', version: '10.6.2.13',                 
    implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'){
    exclude group : 'org.yaml' , module : 'snakeyaml'
    }
    implementation 'org.springframework.retry:spring-retry'
    implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"){
    exclude group : 'org.yaml' , module : 'snakeyaml'
    exclude group: 'org.hibernate.orm', module: 'hibernate-core'
    }
       
    implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:${awsSDKVersion}"
    implementation ("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:${awsSDKVersion}"){
    exclude group : 'org.yaml' , module : 'snakeyaml'
    }
    implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ssm:${awsSDKVersion}"
    implementation "com.xyc.abc.cat:lib-feature-flags:${featureFlagsLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.guava:guava:${guavaVersion}"
    implementation "org.flywaydb:flyway-core:${flywayVersion}"
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.7'
    //  For assuming role in local dev mode
    implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sts:${awsSDKVersion}"
    implementation "org.postgresql:postgresql:${postgresJdbcVersion}"
    /*implementation ("org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:${hibernateVersion}"){
    exclude group : 'javax.persistence' , module : 'javax.persistence-api'
    }*/
    implementation "org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5:${httpclient5}"
    implementation 'jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api'
    testImplementation "cloud.localstack:localstack-utils:${localStackUtilsVersion}"
        testImplementation "org.testcontainers:postgresql:${testPostgresVersion}"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:${junitVersion}"
    testImplementation 'jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
    exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    exclude group : 'org.yaml' , module : 'snakeyaml'
    }
    }
```

Below is gradle.properties file

```
    semanticanalysisVersion=10.6.2.13
    workbenchVersion=10.6.2.13
    junitVersion=4.13.1
    awsSDKVersion=1.11+
    testPostgresVersion=1.15.0
    jacocoVersion=0.8.7
    localStackUtilsVersion=0.1.22
    guavaVersion=31.1-jre
    servicePort=80
    version=22.1.0
    serviceName=auto-discovery-model-generator
    featureFlagsLibVersion=1.0.0-RELEASE
    postgresJdbcVersion=42.4.1
    hibernateVersion=5.4.26.Final
    secretsManagerJdbcVersion=1.0.5
    secretsManagerCacheVersion=1.0.1
    flywayVersion=6.4.3
    httpclient5=5.2
    httpclient5Fluent=5.2
```

while I am getting below error on Jenkins build

```
15:13:59      2023-01-31T09:43:59.527Z  INFO 1626 --- \[    Test worker\]                                             com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Start completed 
15:13:59      2023-01-31T09:43:59.528Z  WARN 1626 --- \[    Test worker\]           o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource \[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class\]: Class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider does not implement the requested interface jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
15:13:59      2023-01-31T09:43:59.529Z  INFO 1626 --- \[    Test worker\] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Shutdown initiated...
15:13:59      2023-01-31T09:43:59.529Z  INFO 1626 --- \[    Test worker\] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Shutdown completed.
15:13:59      2023-01-31T09:43:59.533Z  INFO 1626 --- \[    Test worker\] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :
15:13:59  
15:13:59      Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
15:13:59      2023-01-31T09:43:59.534Z ERROR 1626 --- \[    Test worker\] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

Other portion of log below

```
15:14:04      2023-01-31T09:44:04.890Z  WARN 1626 --- \[    Test worker\] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument
15:14:04      2023-01-31T09:44:04.892Z  INFO 1626 --- \[    Test worker\] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :
15:14:04  
15:14:04      Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
15:14:04      2023-01-31T09:44:04.894Z ERROR 1626 --- \[    Test worker\] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
15:14:04  
15:14:04      \*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
15:14:04      APPLICATION FAILED TO START
15:14:04      \*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
15:14:04  
15:14:04      Description:
15:14:04  
15:14:04      A component required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.
15:14:04  
15:14:04  
15:14:04      Action:
15:14:04  
15:14:04      Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
15:14:04  
15:14:04  
15:14:04  STANDARD_ERROR
15:14:04  
15:14:04
```

I have searched on net and applied those solutions but did not work out
Please suggest any possible solution for this problem with spring boot 3.0

Comment: Please salvage your question and use proper formatting. Currently it is unreadable. What should be formatted (the code and stacktrace) isn't formatted but your actual question is, looks like te wrong way around.

Comment: You seem to be managing a lot of dependencies which should be managed through Spring Boot. However, the main factor is that Spring Boot 3.0.0 comes with the very big breaking change of moving from Jakarta EE 8 / Java EE 8 to Jakarta EE 9+, and that comes with a lot of classes moving from the `javax.*` package namespace to the `jakarta.*` package namespace, and this includes things like the Java Persistence API, so if your code references those classes, you need to update to the new packages, and if you import libraries or plugins, you need to ensure they are also Jakarta EE 9 compatible.

Comment: For example, your code explicitly depends on Hibernate 5.4, but Spring Boot 3 should depend on Hibernate 6 (6.1.6.Final in case of Spring Boot 3.0.2), and Hibernate 5.4 will not work as it still uses the package `javax.persistence` instead of `jakarta.persistence`. Similarly, Spring Boot 3 depends on log4j2 2.19.0, but you pull in 2.17.2.

Comment: The [official migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide) is worth reading, if you haven't already - it covers many of the things that the other commenters have mentioned.

Comment: This is why you should use spring-boot-starter-parent: use the same versions as Spring Boot in your app.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem that probably causes the `entityManagerFactory` issue.

> Below is gradle.properties file
>
> ```
> hibernateVersion=5.4.26.Final
> ```

`Spring boot 3.0.x` supports **Jakarta EE 9** and **Jakarta EE 10**.

So you need to use at least hibernate `5.5.0.Final` version but better to migrate to hibernate `6.x` version. Reason is that `Spring boot 3.0` complies with [Jakarta EE 9](https://jakarta.ee/release/9/) which is based on [Jakarta Persistence 3.0](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/) and this was first implemented into hibernate `5.5.0.Final`.

`Spring boot 3.0` also complies with [Jakarta EE 10](https://jakarta.ee/release/10/) which is based on [Jakarta Persistence 3.1](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.1/) and this was first implemented into hibernate `6.0` version.

The current version of spring boot at the time speaking is `3.0.2` and so if you take a look on the `cli` [version coordinates](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/dependency-versions.html#appendix.dependency-versions.coordinates) which is also the same as what `spring-initializer` uses to create a spring boot project plugging in the right dependencies you can see that it uses for spring boot `3.0.2` the `hibernate-core` version `6.1.6.Final`.

Comment: OP should let Spring Boot manage the versions instead of doing it themselves.